# can you pass information as a property which can be displayed in alert box

Tags: react-native

I want to create an customized alert-box in a way that whatever i pass It should display it accordingly.

https://reactnativecode.com/create-custom-alert-dialog-box/

I used code from above link. What i did is created a new file MyAlertBox.js
added above code and stylesheet. It works fine when i only use `<MyAlertbox />`

Now i want to modify it like below.

`<MyAlertBox title="Information" message="testing customization." show="true" />`

I have removed the button which triggers the alertbox.If i pass show="true" then it should display it otherwise it should not.

How do i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `MyAlertBox` render method, just add something like:

```
render()
{
   if (this.props.show !== "true"){
       return null;
   } else {
      return (<View>
                 ... alertbox rendering....
              </View>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for me. but now if i click any button in it I can not remove the alert as i am using visible={this.props.show} in MyAlertBox what do i do?

Comment: Just use a local state variable in alertbox, e.g. `if (this.props.show !== "true" || this.state.closebuttonpressed === "true"){ return null }`